Request parameters not recognized for GET API endpoint download in express
I am trying to make an API endpoint called GET where an application can resolve a file from an id if it is authenticated by the middleware authenticateUser, the problem is that express can not seem to recognize the URL parameter id
I have tried adding the parameter in different files, for more context there is two files, a router.ts file and download.ts
Contents of download.ts
import client from "../config/database"
import { Router, Request, Response } from "express"
import authenticateUser from "../utils/auth"
const router = Router()

router.get(
  "/:id",
  authenticateUser,
  async (res: Response, req: Request) => {
    const fileId = req.params.id
    

    const file = await client.query(
      "SELECT userid FROM files WHERE id = $1",
      [
        fileId
      ]
    )
    if (file.rows[0].userid == req.user.id) {
      res.download("../uploads/" + req.params.id)
      return res.status(200).send()
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send()
    }
  }
)

export default router

And contents of router.ts
import { Router } from "express"

import signup from "./signup"
import login from "./login"
import upload from "./upload"
import download from "./download"
import ping from "./ping"
import new_dir from "./newDirectory"

const router = Router()

router.use("/signup", signup)
router.use("/login", login)
router.use("/upload", upload)
router.use("/download/", download)
router.use("/ping", ping)
router.use("/new_dir", new_dir)

export default router

As previously mentioned, I have tried adding the parameter in different files like this
I tried adding the id parameter in router.ts like this
router.use("/download/:id", download)

Which wasn't recognized and is seen as undefined
And tried adding it in the download.ts
router.get(
  "/:id",
  authenticateUser,
  // Main func here
)

Reading this question, I have modified the code like this in router.ts
router.use(
  "/download/:id", 
  (req, res, next) => { // Add a function to assign request params to another variable that can be read by the handler
    req.parameters = {}
    req.parameters.fileId = 2
    next();
  },
  download
)

But the error still persists stating that the variable is undefined there is no obvious solution I can find.
Here is the full log from the terminal
D:\Websites\picture-upload-download-platform\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95
    fn(req, res, next);
    ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fileId')
    at D:\Websites\picture-upload-download-platform\backend\src\routes\download.ts:10:35
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Websites\picture-upload-download-platform\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Websites\picture-upload-download-platform\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at authenticateUser (D:\Websites\picture-upload-download-platform\backend\src\utils\auth.ts:37:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Everything I have tried hasn't worked. Sorry in advance, I am still new to asking questions so forgive me if the question is not clear or improperly formatted :(
EDIT
Here is my authentication middleware used for endpoints like upload
const authenticateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  const authToken = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authToken == undefined || !authToken) {
    return res.status(401).send()
  }
  const [prefix, token] = authToken!?.split(" ", 2) // TODO: Handle invalid prefixes
  try {
    const sessionQueryResult = await client.query(
      "SELECT user_id FROM user_sessions WHERE token=$1",
      [token]
    );
    
    if (Object.keys(sessionQueryResult.rows).length == 0) {
      return res.status(401).send();
    }
    
    const userId = await sessionQueryResult.rows[0].user_id

    const userQueryResult = await client.query(
      "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=$1",
      [parseInt(userId as string)]
    );

    if (userQueryResult.rowCount === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }

    req.user = {
      id: userId,
      username: userQueryResult.rows[0].username,
      token_type: prefix
    };
    
    next(); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error in authentication:", error);
    return res.status(500).send(); 
  }
};


Hi, Thank you for the post. If possible please include auth.ts as well. Also please check that download.ts posted is the latest one.

Hi @WeDoTheBest4You,  I've added the file used for authentication, however I can't seem to find anything wrong with it

Now I understood that the real issue was something else as answered here, and I troubled you unnecessarily for this update. Sorry for that.

Your method signature is backwards:
async (res: Response, req: Request) => {
    const fileId = req.params.id

Ought to be
async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const fileId = req.params.id

See the Express routing guide

It worked! I can't express how thankful I am, enjoy the extra reputation :D (after it lets me)
